# PHP inserting tweets into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, twitter

I am using the reference from [Inserting data from Twitter API into a MySQL Database using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175316/inserting-data-from-twitter-api-into-a-mysql-database-using-php) to insert tweets into mysql database. But i am getting PHP "Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'id_str' cannot be null". Even if I use another variable like 'created_at', I am getting the same error.

Is it because the json is not properly parsed? Below is the code snippet:

```
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$getfield = '?q='.urlencode("#f1").'&count=10'.'&tweet_mode=extended';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$tweets = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
foreach($tweets as $tweet){
    $created_at = $tweet['created_at'];
    $id_str = $tweet['id_str'];

    <PHP PREPARED STATEMENTs FOR INSERTING etc>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolved it:

Have to use:

```
foreach($tweets['statuses'] as $tweet)
```

instead of

```
foreach($tweets as $tweet)
```

Not sure why it is returned this way though. But it works!